# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Solution (wrong name: solution)

Tags: java, compiler-errors

```
class solution
{
    void table(final int n) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(n + " X " + i + " = " + n * i);
        }
    }
}

class Solution {
    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        solution os = new solution();
        Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = ob.nextInt();
        os.table(n);
    }
}
```

After running java Solution
this is the error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Solution (wrong name: solution)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1017)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:821)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:719)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:642)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:600)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        at Solution.main(table.java:13)
```

could not find the solution for it this error starts popping when I have upgraded to Java 14 earlier I have java 8 this code runs with no problem.

Comment: How do you compile your classes?

Comment: first i write javac filename.java then java Solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always follow best practices. Don't use the same name for class in the same package.

```
package com.india.demo;

public class solution
{
    public void table(final int n) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(n + " X " + i + " = " + n * i);
        }
    }
}
------------------
package com.india.string;

import java.util.Scanner;

import com.india.demo.solution;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        solution os = new solution();
        Scanner ob = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = ob.nextInt();
        os.table(n);
    }
}

This will work.
```